# Adding a dummy variable to tdm matrix

Tags: r, machine-learning, tm

This is how I got my tdm matrix:

```
    doc.vec <- VectorSource(data$text)
    doc.corpus <- Corpus(doc.vec)
    tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(doc.corpus, control = list(wordLengths = c(2, Inf)))
```

My original tdm matrix looks like:

```
           doc1    doc2    doc3 ... doc10000

    term1    .        1      1   ...     1
    term2    .        .      1   ...     .
    ...
    term99   1        .      1   ...     1
```

What I want is:

```
               doc1     doc2    doc3 ... doc10000   class       
   term1          .       1      1   ...     1        1
   term2          .       .      1   ...     .        0
   ...
   term99         1       .      1   ...     1        0
```

where class is a 0/1 dummy indicating whether the term is contained in class 0 or class 1.
I have this class dummy defined in my original data, called by data$class. 
And I am wondering if there is a way to ``transfer" this variable into my tdm.

Thank you so much.

Edit: Sorry for being unclear earlier -- my original class dummy was for documents, not for terms. And what I am trying to do is to re-assign the class to terms, so that 1 denotes that a term only appears in class 1, and 0 means it only appears in class 0.

Comment: `tdm$class <- data$class`

Comment: Also, `cbind(tdm, data$class)` should work.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear early -- my original class dummy was for documents, not for terms. And what I am trying to do is to re-assign the classes to terms, so that 1 denotes a term only appears in class 1, and 0 means it only appears in class 0

Answer (score 0):

You can have a tdm or a document term matrix (dtm) instead, it is not very clear what you want to get out of it but the second one helps when you have a class per document, for example:

```
                term1     term2    term3 ... term10000   class      
   doc1          .         1        1   ...     1        1
   doc2          .         .        1   ...     .        0
   ...
  doc99          1         .        1   ...     1        0
```

Now you can use this for training a model (classifier) to predict your class for new documents. The easier way to get this done is by converting it the dtm into a dataframe than attach the class column and thats it:

```
dtmDataFrame <- as.data.frame(inspect(dtm))
```

The other thing you mentioned here " re-assign the classes to terms, so that 1 denotes a term only appears in class 1, and 0 means it only appears in class 0" does not make much sense to me, what will you do with terms that are not in your class 1 and 0? filter them out? what is your intention?